# unity sphere falls through the plane

Tags: unity

I have a elongated rigidbody sphere with Mesh Collider. It falls through the plane. (I made a rigidbody cube and does not fall through.)

I have problem with Mesh Collider repeately.. The collision of the object is not detected.

If I replace the mesh collider with box collider, it collides again.

I would like to collide a mesh collider with another mesh collider.

Comment: It sounds like you've solved the problem with the rigid body cube. You've described what troubles you're having, but you haven't asked a question. Can you edit your question to include a question? (Please don't ask "How to solve this?" or something similar, be specific about what problem you're trying to solve and why the methods you've tried already aren't a solution).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Mesh Collider can not collide with another Mesh Collider unless Convex is checked on the Collider in question.

This is described in the Unity3D documentation: http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Components/class-MeshCollider.html

Comment: yes that works, though if the mesh is set to none. It does not.